# configuring push queue for not retrying

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine documentation about Push Queues it is mentioned that Task Queues should be idempotent.

> When implementing the code for tasks (as worker URLs within your app),
>   it is important to consider whether the task is idempotent. App
>   Engine's Task Queue API is designed to only invoke a given task once;
>   however, it is possible in exceptional circumstances that a task may
>   execute multiple times (such as in the unlikely case of major system
>   failure). Thus, your code must ensure that there are no harmful
>   side-effects of repeated execution.

Now I want to configure tasks to not to retry on failing. How can I do that with queue.xml? and with this configuration app engine will not execute same task multiple times in exceptional circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/queue#Java_Configuring_retry_attempts_for_failed_tasks):

> In push queues, you can specify your own scheme for task retries by
>   adding the [retry_parameters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/queue#retry_parameters) directive in **queue.yaml**.

I'd set **task_retry_limit** to 0.

But I'm not sure if this would help in the exceptional circumstances. The advice in your quoted paragraph suggests it *might* not always do so.

You could use the datastore to precisely track/block task execution attempts that reach the critical sections of your app code - in other words ensuring that there are no harmful side-effects of repeated execution (i.e. following the advice).